# Order by two columns depending on if null with Laravel and MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a nullable relation that sometimes fallbacks to a string. So, when sorting my results I would like to combine the `brands.name` and the `ads.mixed_brand_name`.

Example of how I would like the order:

1. `brands.name`: `Audi` `mixed_brand_name`: `null`
2. `brands.name`: `null` `mixed_brand_name`: `BMW blabla`
3. `brands.name`: `Citroën` `mixed_brand_name`: `null`

This is what I am doing right now, but all *Ads* with a *Brand* comes first (since the `brand_id` is null on those without a brand relationship.

```
Ad::join('brands', 'brands.id', '=', 'ads.brand_id')
    ->orderBy('brands.name')
    ->orderBy('ads.mixed_brand_name');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom order by [orderByRaw](https://laraveldaily.com/know-orderbyraw-eloquent/)

```
Ad::leftJoin('brands', 'brands.id', '=', 'ads.brand_id')
    ->orderByRaw('IFNULL(brands.name, ads.mixed_brand_name)');
```

Comment: Just figured it out before you posted, haha. But thanks! Although, I needed to use a `leftJoin()` since the relationship was nullable.